# Regex to block a phone number that contains same digit more than 4 times successively?

Tags: javascript, php, regex

i would like to add a regex to check if a phone number contains the same digits more than n times.
this is what i tried :

```
  ^0[1-9]([-. ]?[0-9]{2}){4}$
```

how can i make it ?
thanks.

Comment: To help us better understand your issue, can you give some example numbers and highlight which of those you would like to catch. Thanks!

Comment: Thnx Chappell for your feedback, i have to block phone number like  : 0600000450 or 0511111320 or 0425888888

Comment: You can use `{4,}` to match 4 or more times.

Comment: @ThePerplexedOne that fails to capture repeating characters. You can just do `'06000000000'.test(/([0-9])\1{4,}/);` which will check for any number that repeats 4 or more times anywhere i the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to check for any repeating character n times or more. First we need to determine which characters we want to catch. Second we need to get that single character from the capture group using the backslash + n. Finally we need to say how many times it should repeat from. In this scenario I don't think it needs to validate the entire number, just the fact there are the same repeated characters. So in order to catch any repeating number 4 or more times we can do:

```
'06000000000'.test(/([0-9])\1{3,}/); // return true
'12344445678'.test(/([0-9])\1{3,}/); // return true
'01234567890'.test(/([0-9])\1{3,}/); // return false
```

`([0-9])` this is what we want to check, in this case any number from 0 to 9

`\1` get the value from the first capture group

`{3,}` check this value is repeating 3 or more times, because we've already got that first character matched in our capture group. 3 + 1 = 4 naturally.

Answer (score 0):

you may try this pattern:

```
(\d)\1{3,}
```

(\d) indicates digits number

(\d)\1 Matches the digits of a numbered subexpression

(\d)\1{2,} matches the digits 1+2 and more times.

(\d)\1{3,} matches the digits 1+3 and more times.

(\d)\1{3} matches exactly 1+3 times

\1 counts 1 already. That's why \1{3} is 1+3.

Answer (score 0):

You could go for

```
^\d*(\d)\1{3}\d*$
```

These numbers can be discarded, see [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/rOUilO/1).